# Why are numpy arrays made from images 10 times the size of the original images and what can I do about it?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am downloading images, chopping them up in various ways, and then saving them to disk for processing later.  The images themselves are usually <1M, but they get a lot bigger when I load them into numpy and then save them as numpy arrays.

Here's a simple example:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
os.system("wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/3a/Feral_goat_in_Aruba.JPG/1440px-Feral_goat_in_Aruba.JPG")
img = plt.imread("1440px-Feral_goat_in_Aruba.JPG")
np.save("goat_array.npy", img)
os.system("ls -lh | grep goat")

-rw-rw-r-- 1 becky becky 472K Dec 14 10:51 1440px-Feral_goat_in_Aruba.JPG
-rw-rw-r-- 1 becky becky 4.5M Dec 14 10:56 goat_array.npy
```

I'm keeping the datatype as `uint8`, so IDK what else to do.  Please let me know why this happens, and what I can do to keep the size of the array down.

And, my eventual goal will be to stuff images into a hdf5 file.  Please let me know if that brings on any additional considerations.

Thanks!

Comment: JPEG is a highly compressed image storage format. If you expand it back out into the pixels that make up the image it is bound to take more space. What can you do? Keep them as JPEGs.

Comment: My first guess would be that's because your numpy images are uncompressed.

Comment: So if I want an array of numbers, this is basically inevitable?

Comment: @generic_user Basically yes. You can try a lossless image format like e. g. PNG or a generic compression algorithm (bzip, xz,...) to intermediately store the image but these may not work very effectively depending on image content.

Comment: A JPEG file is also just a list of binary numbers. It depends what you want to do with the bits you chop up. You can store the compressed JPEG-encoded file and decode it on-demand if you want to, but it depends what you are trying to do.